# setInterval not repeating when nested in a click event

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a code snippet am trying to twig to replace browsers native `audio` HTML element. I am caling the `play()` method on the `audio` element ones a `button` is clicked and then keep updating the `currentTime` of the file every second via `setInterval`.

But I have to click the listener object (`button`) every time to update the timer. When I move the code out of the jQuery on-click block, I get a timer value set to NaN.

How do I update the timer without clicking the button every second? And why do I get a Not a number error when out of the block?

This are my sample codes:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-/Y6pD6FV/Vv2HJnA6t+vslU6fwYXjCFtcEpHbNJ0lyAFsXTsjBbfaDjzALeQsN6M" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-h0AbiXch4ZDo7tp9hKZ4TsHbi047NrKGLO3SEJAg45jXxnGIfYzk4Si90RDIqNm1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">

<style>
.hidden-audio-wrapper{display:none}
input{
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  width: 160px;
  height: 20px;
  margin: 10px 50px;
  background: linear-gradient(to left,  #f3f3f3 0%, #007bff 80%);
  /* background: linear-gradient(to right, #f3f3f3 0%, #f3f3f3 100%); */
  background-size: 150px 10px;
  background-position: center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  overflow: hidden;
  outline: none;
  zoom: 100%;
  display: block;
  margin: auto;
  -webkit-outline-radius: 25px;
  border-radius:10px;
  margin-bottom: 30px;
}

input::-webkit-slider-thumb {
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  border: 1px solid;
  -webkit-outline-radius: 25px;
  border-radius:10px;
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  background: #f2f2f2;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 3;
}

input::-webkit-slider-thumb:after {
  content: " ";
  width: 160px;
  height: 10px;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1;
  right: 20px;
  top: 5px;
  background: #2ecc71;
}

input[type="range"]::-ms-fill-lower,
input[type="range"]::-ms-fill-upper {
  background: transparent;
}

input[type="range"]::-ms-track {
  border-radius: 8px;
  height: 7px;
  border: 1px solid #bdc3c7;
  background-color: #fff;
}

input[type="range"]::-ms-thumb {
  background-color: #ecf0f1;
  border: 1px solid #bdc3c7;
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  border-radius: 10px;
  cursor: pointer;
}
</style>

<input type="button" id="audio-rep-id" value="click here to play" />
```

And this is my JavaScript:

```
<script>
$('#audio-rep-id').click(function() {

  var aud = document.getElementById("audio-file-id"); 
  aud.play();
  curTime = parseInt(aud.currentTime); 
  durTime = parseInt(aud.duration);

  setInterval(function (){
    if(durTime > 59){
      var bit_1 = durTime / 60;
      bit_1 = Math.floor(bit_1);
      var bit_2 =   durTime % 60;
      bit_2  = bit_2 * 60; 
      if(bit_1 < 10){
        $('#total_Time').text('0' + bit_1 + ':' + bit_2/60);
      }else{ $('#total_Time').text(bit_1 + ':' + bit_2/60);}

    }else{$('#total_Time').text('00:' + durTime);}

    if(curTime > 59){
      var bit_1 = curTime / 60;
      bit_1 = Math.floor(bit_1);
      var bit_2 =   curTime % 60;
      bit_2  = bit_2 * 60; 
      if(bit_1 < 10){
        $('#current_Time').text('0' + bit_1 + ':' + bit_2/60);
      }else{ $('#current_Time').text(bit_1 + ':' + bit_2/60);}

    }else{$('#current_Time').text('00:' + curTime);}

  },1000);
});

var aud = document.getElementById("audio-file-id"); 
$('#').click(function() {
  aud.play();
});

</script>
```

And then my HTML:

```
<div class="hidden-audio-wrapper1">
  <audio controls id="audio-file-id">
    <source src="horse.ogg" type="audio/ogg">
    <source src="horse.mp3" type="audio/mpeg">
    Your browser does not support the audio element.
  </audio>
</div>


<div class="d-flex flex-row text-primary primary" style="background-color:#f9f9f9; width:80%; height:40px; border-radius:35px; border:1px solid;">
  <div class="p-2">
    <input id="progress" type="range" value="40" />
  </div> 
  <div class="p-2">
    <span class="fa fa-play-circle fa-lg" style="font-size:28px; "></span>
    <span class="fa fa-pause-circle fa-lg" style="font-size:28px; display:none"></span>
  </div>
  <div id = "time" class="p-2"> 
    <span id="total_Time">00:00</span> -  
  </div>
  <div id = "time" class="p-2"><span id="current_Time">00:00</span>
  </div>
  <div class="p-2">
    <input id="volume" style="width:50px; zoom:100%;" type="range" value="40" />
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: only the code INSIDE the setinterval callback is executed every second ... you run `curTime = parseInt(aud.currentTime); 
                durTime = parseInt(aud.duration);` on click, no in the interval, so of course curTime and durTime don't change

Comment: are you suggesting that I wrap the on-click with the setInterval callback function?

Comment: No.. he his telling you to move the `curTime` & `durTime` assignments into your setInterval callback, otherwise like he said, the values are not going to update..

Comment: Also try using an editor with good linting, your curTime & durTime are going to be polluting the global. eg.. `var curTime = parseInt(aud.currentTime); `

Comment: was really that simple! ouch.. thanks all.. cheers mate! editors like which? any suggestions? i use notepad++, serves me well

Comment: https://www.slant.co/topics/1686/~javascript-ides-or-editors